# Highlight and Annotate text in AePubReader iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, epub

Is there any way to get text position for mark up and make note on ePub file ? I want to put highlight and add note feature on ePub file.

I am referring https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader as a basic start. This code already facilitates searching and font size varying feature.

Please suggest me anyway to achieve my requirement with this library.

Thanks in advance.